# How to prevent updating/deleting a MySQL record when not using a primary key?

Tags: mysql, sql-injection, database-trigger

I have a MySQL table containing information about songs, which has a primary key and a secondary unique key.  In my web-application the song's primary key is not 'sent' to the client, but a secondary unique key is that is not displayed by the browser, so that the web-app can update and delete each of the songs, one at a time.

Is there a way, possibly using a delete trigger and/or a stored procedure, to prevent a song's data row from being updated/deleted except when both the primary key **AND** the secondary unique key are specified in the MySQL command?

In my web-app the user can update/delete a song's data row, but they should only do this by 'posting' a request to the server that contains a command parameter with the values '**update**' or '**delete**' and the secondary unique key of the song to be deleted, plus any other necessary data in the case of an update.  Then the server looks up the song's primary key and performs the update/delete, which is 'caught' by the update/delete trigger, and only allowed to perform the actual update/delete when both the primary and  secondary keys are specified, sort of a 'two-factor' protection mechanism.

This way a malicious user who tries to perform some sort of SQL injection attack to change or delete a song's data records won't likely be able to do so because they won't know both of the required keys, where as injecting SQL commands with a guessed primary keys might otherwise get past the SQL injection prevention code.

It's either this or a switch that must be turned on before deletes or updates of the song data are permitted, which also rely on update/delete triggers.

I know about using prepared SQL statements and not letting using the user entered data be used directly in a SQL update/delete command as a means to protect against SQL injection attacks, but I'm not sure that these always work and the song data is so critical that I want to extra protection against malicious changes/deletes in case a user tries to update/delete song data without using the permitted means provided by the web-app.

Thanks

Comment: I don't think there's a way to do this. Triggers don't get the WHERE criteria that was used to select the rows to be deleted. Just make sure you're safe from SQL injection.

Comment: Another option is to not allow deleting at all. Instead of deleting rows, add an `active` column and just set it to `0` to indicate that the row is not currently in use.

Comment: You could restrict DELETE privilege to a stored procedure, and make clients run that procedure. The procedure has two arguments, so the client must specify both. The DELETE in the procedure body uses those two arguments as the values for both PK and unique key, so there's no way anyone can avoid specifying both. If they don't, the DELETE simply affects no rows.

Comment: Any decent ORM will automatically protect you against SQL Injection. Also, PreparedStatements are safe against SQL Injection when properly used. You definitively should NOT delete the rows, but maybe "deactivate" them only.

Comment: If the data is so critical you should *version* it, in order to keep all versions of each row. Never delete a row, and keep good daily backups of the database.

Comment: I wouldn't let users 'hard delete' data, unless there was a regulatory requirement to allow it

Comment: Thank you all for your comments.  Bill Karwin, your idea about limiting the deletes (and updates) to stored procedures with the two parameters sounds like what I was looking for, would you please provide me a link on how to grant permissions to a stored procedure so I can learn more about this?  Or are you actually saying that I need to create a new connection for a user who has this permission and call the stored procedure with that user, in which case why not just remove the delete/update permission from the user that I mainly use to select the data that gets displayed in my web-application?

Comment: As to deactivating the song rows versus hard-deleting them, I've got legal constraints that require that the song data rows actually be deleted, because I don't own the songs and am only allowed to 'hold' them while the actual owner agrees to my doing so. If/When the owner revokes this, then they must be able to actually delete their song's data from my database.  Besides, the space taken by the songs and the associated date takes up space I otherwise need.

Comment: I don't know what the performance impact would be if I partition the database into two parts, but if I 'stubbed' deleted songs, eliminating the song file and non-public date elements, and moved those records into the second partition, then I wouldn't have to hard-delete  them.  The active/non-deleted rows would be in the 'primary' partition.  Since I've never worked with partitioned databases, in MySQL or any other databases, I don't know the impact or feasibility of this.  Any ideas?